# Scala Operation on TimeStamp values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the input in timestamp , based on some condition i need to minus 1 sec or minus 3 months using scala programming

Input:

```
val date :String = "2017-10-31T23:59:59.000"
```

Output:

For Minus 1 sec

```
val lessOneSec = "2017-10-31T23:59:58.000"
```

For Minus 3 Months

```
val less3Mon   = "2017-07-31T23:59:58.000"
```

How to convert a string value to Timestamp and do the operations like minus in scala programming ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are working with Dataframes, since you have the spark-dataframe tag.

You can use the SQL INTERVAL to reduce the time, but your column should be in `timestamp` format for that:

```
df.show(false)
+-----------------------+
|ts                     |
+-----------------------+
|2017-10-31T23:59:59.000|
+-----------------------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("minus1Sec" , date_format($"ts".cast("timestamp") - expr("interval 1 second") , "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") )
  .withColumn("minus3Mon" , date_format($"ts".cast("timestamp") - expr("interval 3 month ") , "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS") )
  .show(false)

+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|ts                     |minus1Sec              |minus3Mon              |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|2017-10-31T23:59:59.000|2017-10-31T23:59:58.000|2017-07-31T23:59:59.000|
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: yes I am working on Spark Dataframes and need an custom udf to perform this

Comment: @raam this should be the accepted answer for future newcomers !

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code

```
val yourDate = "2017-10-31T23:59:59.000"
val formater = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
val date = LocalDateTime.parse(yourDate, formater)
println(date.minusSeconds(1).toString(formater))
println(date.minusMonths(3).toString(formater))
```

> Output

```
2017-10-31T23:59:58.000
2017-07-31T23:59:59.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the jodatime library. it has all the APIs you need to minus seconds or months from a timestamp

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

sbt dependency

```
"joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.9"
```

Comment: ya i tried that .and the final output is coming with +11:00 at the end.

Comment: val input = new org.joda.time.DateTime("2017-10-30T00:00:00.000")   ; val minusOneSec = input.minusSeconds(1) and the output is 2017-10-29T23:59:59.000+11:00 . How do i convert it to the parent date format ?

Comment: DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

Comment: I believe it's relevant to quote from their site, to the advantage of users of Java 8 (and beyond): "Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project."